# Graphing of server data using Neo4j on client PCs

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4jclient

Now I have two PCs, a client PC and a server PC, with Neo4j installed on each PC.
When graphing data on the server PC, I used to connect from the client PC to the server PC via a remote desktop connection and graph the data using Neo4j installed on the server PC.

However, from now on, I would like to graph data on the server PC using Neo4j installed on the client PC, instead of using Neo4j installed on the server PC.
So I created a new Project on the client PC's Neo4j Desktop, referring to the official Neo4j page, and went to "Add -> Remote Connection", but I did not know what to specify for the "Connect URL" and "Username/Password". I have been unable to specify what to specify in the "Connect URL" and "Username/Password" fields.[image][image]
When connecting from a client PC to a server PC via remote desktop connection, I have specified the IP address (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd), ID, and password of the server PC to connect to the server.

I would be very grateful if you, the experts, could give me some advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the right "Connect URL" value to use in Neo4j Desktop to connect to a remote Neo4j server (given that you already know how to use a browser like Chrome to connect to the remote server) is to slightly alter the browser URL.

For example, suppose you use this URL (in the browser) to connect to the Neo4j Browser on the server:

```
http://my-server.example.com:7474/browser/
```

The correct "Connect URL" value to use would be (you can also use `neo4j` instead of `bolt`):

```
bolt://my-server.example.com:7687
```

Comment: Dear cybersam, Thank you for your prompt advice.
Thank you very much for showing me how to visualize the data on the server PC with Neo4j on the client PC. Before using Neo4j Desktop, I found that Neo4j on the server PC would time out in the client PC's browser and would not start up.
(http://my-server.example.com:7474/browser/). Is it necessary to permit to any external access from the client PC browser?Note that the client OS is Windows 11 and the server OS is Windows Server 2019.
Anyway, your answer is very informative and I would like to take it as the best answer.

Comment: Yes, the server must be configured to allow access to your client. That is a very big topic, and you should investigate how to do that on Windows Server.